# Question : 3 Of Section : Solvability by Radicals Hungerford' s Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $K$ be a field, $f \in  K[x] $ an irreducible polynomial of degree $n \geq 5$  and $F$ a splitting
> field of $f$ over $K$. Assume that $\operatorname{Aut}_K{F}$ is isomorphic to $S_n $. Let $u$ be a root of $f$ in $F$. Then

(a) Show that $\operatorname{Aut}_K {K(u)}  =1$ and $[K(u):K]=n$.

(b) There is no radical extension field $E$ of $K$ such that $K \subset  K(u) \subset  E$.

(c) Every normal closure over $K$ that contains u also contains an isomorphic
copy of $F$.

I have proved that $[K(u): K] =n$ , but I don't know how to show that for all $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}_K {K(u)} $ and for all $v \in K(u)$  we have $\sigma(v)= v$ and (b) although I have done (c).

I have thought a lot about this question and I will not be able to do it by myself.

So, Please guide me..

Answer (score 1):

For (a): Note that the $K$-automorphisms of $K(u)$ correspond bijectively to the conjugates of $u$ over $K$ contained in $K(u)$, so we want to show that $u$ is the only root of $f$ in $K(u)$. Assume that there is some other root $v$ of $f$ contained in $K(u)$. Then we may divide $f$ by $(x-u)(x-v)$ over $K(u)$ to get a polynomial of degree $n-2$. This will have a splitting field of degree at most $(n-2)!$ over $K(u)$. Hence $f$ has a splitting field of degree at most $n\cdot(n-2)!$ but this is a contradiction as we know that the splitting field has $K$-automorphism group $S_n$ and hence degree at least $n!$.
For (b): Since the splitting field of a polynomial of degree $n$ always has degree at most $n!$ and $[F:K]\geq|\operatorname{Aut}_KF|=n!$ we see that $[F:K]=n!$. So in particular $F/K$ is separable and we may apply the following theorem:

> A finite separable extension $E/K$ is contained in a radical extension iff the Galois-group of its normal hull is solvable.

In this case $E=K(u)$. Since $F$ is the normal closure of $E$ and $G(F/K)=S_n$ is not solvable (as $n\geq5$) we see that $K(u)$ cannot be contained in some radical extension.
**Edit:** The 'separable' property is actually only needed for the other direction of the above theorem (i.e. if the group is solvable then the extension is solvable by radicals), so we technically didn't need to show that.